# CSS compatibility IE and Firefox

Tags: css, compatibility

I'm trying to move my color palette and I used the code below

```
     margin-left :90px !important;
```

It sure work on IE and I thought my goal is done. Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't have the same result as IE. My color palette didn't even move a single bit to where it should be. I tried almost everything but its not working on Firefox at all. I hope anyone can give me some idea how to fix it. Thank you :)

Comment: @Harikrishnan: please don't use code spans (`like this`) where it  isn't actual code or a keyword in the programming language related to the question. For example, `margin-left` or `!important` is acceptable to put in code spans, but `Firefox` or `help me` shouldn't be. Thanks!

Comment: @Lyn Could you kindly please reproduce your problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?